# Files.readAllLines skips last line

Tags: java, xml

am reading xml file in List in such a way:

```
List<String> file_lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
```

My file has 317 lines, but in list appears 316. Main problem is that lat one is empty (just carriage return probably)
How can I deal with this? I need precisely every line of file, because am calculating crc32 checksum for file validation.

Comment: I think in this case you should not use the text input modes but rather read the bytes of the file directly using a `FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need precisely every line of file, because am calculating crc32 checksum for file validation.

In that case, you are reading it the wrong way.  You need to read it and checksum it as bytes rather than characters:

- to avoid problems with text transcoding issues,
- to avoid the problem of dealing with the last line of the file (which may or may not have an end of line ...), and
- to avoid having to deal with variants in end-of-line markers ... that you typically cannot distinguish with a "read line" or "read all lines" API method.